# Firefox Addon SDK: Loading addon file into iframe

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to load a `resource://` link, respectively a local file from my Firefox addon into an `iframe` in a web page.

The reason is, that the resource should be visually embedded into the web page while not giving the website access to it's DOM for security reasons.

The issue has been discussed in various places in the past, e.g. here (without solution):
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=792479

As most of the postings are rather old, I want to ask, if in the meantime there are any new solutions or workarounds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I suggested in the bug or in the ML of jetpack a terrible workaround, that basically is convert your `resource://` in a `data:` url (using `data.load` to load the HTML content, and then encode and append as prefix, so something like that should works:

```
/* main.js */
const { data } = require('sdk/self');

// just an example, you can use `tab.attach` too
require('sdk/page-mod').PageMod({
  include: '*',
  contentScriptFile: data.url('content.js'),
  contentScriptOptions: {
    content: encodeURIComponent(data.load('index.html'))
  }
});

/* content.js */
let iframe = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'));

iframe.setAttribute('sandbox', 'allow-scripts');
// maybe you want also use the seamless attribute, see:
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

iframe.contentWindow.location.href = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + self.options.content;
```

It's a workaround of course, and I hope that the bug you mentioned will be fixed soon.
Notice that in this way you cannot communicate directly from the iframe to the parent's document, but it means also that you can't do the way around, that is what you want to prevent.

Of course, you can still use the add-on code to communicate between your iframe and the parent's document (you need to attach content scripts and use `port` and `postMessage`).

**Edit:** changed the way the url is set, otherwise getting the `src` attribute from the parent's document is *still* possible, and contains whole HTML.

Comment: Thank you. Can't the parent document regain access to the iframe's content by removing the sandbox attribute?

Comment: **Edit:** No it can't. Changes to the `sandbox` attribute are only applied on reload of the page.

Comment: With all the recent enhancements to the Jetpack API, is this still the best technique available to get this kind of iframe functionality working?

Comment: I still see that if we try to set resource:// as the src for iframe it never loads. But the target page I want add on to work on has CSP to block frame-src schema data: I am using Firefox AddOn sdk.

Comment: On some pages (e.g., gmail and github) I'm getting an error with this solution: "...result = 2153644038"

Answer (score 2):

I used [a solution proposed here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=792479#c20).

It is implemented by creating a special protocol that is handled by your Firefox addon, which in turn requests the resources from its folder.

Note that in case the resource folder may contain something non-public then I would add additional checks to allow only these resources that really are intended to be web-accessible.

The custom-protocol code attached to the post mentioned above is [available here](https://bug792479.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=8395788):

```
/*
Makes any file within the data directory available to use in an iframe.
Replace this: require("sdk/self").data.url(...)
With this: require("name-of-this-file").url(...)
*/
var { Class } = require('sdk/core/heritage');
var { Unknown, Factory } = require('sdk/platform/xpcom');
var { Cc, Ci, Cr } = require('chrome');
var self = require("sdk/self");

var resourceProtocolHandler = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
    .getService(Ci.nsIIOService)
    .getProtocolHandler('resource');

var scheme = "res-" + self.id.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9+\-\.]/g, "-");

var AddonProtocolHandler = Class({
    extends: Unknown,
    interfaces: ['nsIProtocolHandler'],

    scheme: scheme,
    defaultPort: -1,
    protocolFlags: Ci.nsIProtocolHandler.URI_STD
        | Ci.nsIProtocolHandler.URI_LOADABLE_BY_ANYONE
        | Ci.nsIProtocolHandler.URI_SAFE_TO_LOAD_IN_SECURE_CONTEXT,

    newURI: function(spec, originCharset, baseURI) {
        let uri = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/standard-url;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIStandardURL);
        uri.init(uri.URLTYPE_STANDARD, this.defaultPort, spec, originCharset, baseURI);
        return uri.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIURI);
    },

    newChannel: function(uri) {
        if (uri.spec.indexOf(exports.url("")) != 0) {
            throw Cr.NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE;
        }
        var resourceUri = resourceProtocolHandler.newURI(uri.spec.replace(scheme + "://", "resource://"), uri.originCharset, null);
        var channel = resourceProtocolHandler.newChannel(resourceUri);
        channel.originalURI = uri;
        return channel;
    },

    allowPort: (port, scheme) => false
});

Factory({
    contract: "@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=" + scheme,
    Component: AddonProtocolHandler
});

exports.url = function(url) {
    return self.data.url(url).replace("resource://", scheme + "://");
};
```

**Additional note**: for `page` scripts (not `content` scripts) this custom protocol helps in loading an `iframe` and other HTML elements, but not in loading a `XMLHttpRequest` or `Worker`. For the latter, still cross-origin restrictions apply and a security error is raised: "Access to restricted URI denied" in case of `XMLHttpRequest`, and "The operation is insecure." for `Worker`. 

In contrast, under Chrome the `XMLHttpRequest` to `web_accessible_resources` is permitted. `Worker` does not implement access to `web_accessible_resources` under Chrome either.

**BUT** for `Workers` you can use this custom-protocol url for `importScripts` method. Using that you can also work around the problem of loading custom resources into `Workers`. This code works also in Chrome, as an alternative to using `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
var code = "self.onmessage = function (message)\
{\
    self.onmessage = null;\
    self.importScripts(message.data);\
};";

var blob = new Blob([code], {type: 'application/javascript'});
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var w = new Worker(blobUrl);
w.postMessage(*webAccessibleResourceUrl*);
URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [zer0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1262551/zer0)'s idea. However, on pages with a content-security-policy I got an exception (...result = 2153644038). 
For that reason, I add my domain to the content-security-policy of the response header:

```
//main.js 
var { Cc, Ci } = require('chrome');

var observer = {
    observe : function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
      if (aTopic == "http-on-examine-response") {
        aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
        var csp = aSubject.getResponseHeader("content-security-policy");
        if(csp.indexOf('frame-src') > -1) {
            var cspParts = csp.split(';');
            for (var i=0; i<cspParts.length; i++) {
                if(cspParts[i].indexOf('frame-src') > -1) {
                    cspParts[i] += ' yourdomain.tld';
                    break;
                }
            }
            aSubject.setResponseHeader("content-security-policy", cspParts.join(';'), false);
        } 
      }
    }
}; 
var observerService = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
observerService.addObserver(observer, "http-on-examine-response", false);

//content-script.js 
iframe.src = yourdomain.tld/...
```

**EDIT**: This code might be rejected by a FF reviewer with: "Modifying 'content-security-policy' is not allowed for security reasons."