# Loading an iframe via firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm loading an iframe with an extension-local html page, using this method: 
[Firefox Addon SDK: Loading addon file into iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082162/firefox-addon-sdk-loading-addon-file-into-iframe/21132801#21132801)

It works great, with one issue: It seems that certain pages with strict content security policies block the iframe, for example Github. Is there a way around this in a Firefox extension?

UPDATE:

Additional info:
- This doesn't appear to be an issue in Chrome extensions.

Comment: For bootstrap addons we have to use `contentaccessible=yes` in the `chrome.manifest` as done here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9406437  for addon-sdk if you are using `data.url('you file name')` it shouldn't give you issues i dont think.

Comment: Is this going to work with multi-process? I think you would need to use the new frame script method.