# What are set of whitelisting urls for Firefox CSP?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, content-security-policy

As in case of Google Chrome browser [Google Chrome CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) 
There are whitelisting of origins -

> Currently, we allow whitelisting origins with the following schemes:
>   blob, filesystem, https, chrome-extension, and
>   chrome-extension-resource.

Is there any listing of such origins for Firefox. We are trying to write an add on for Firefox which will need to load as an iframe.

I currently get following CSP error when I am trying to load a frame.html read from my addon XPI resources. Its a frame which then loads the actual frame.

> Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at data:text/html;

iframe with chrome-extensions:// as the path works for Chrome browser nothing like that is available for Firefox. (atleast I am unable to trace such a thing)

Please give us some suggestion if we can do a path to get iframe extension working.

Comment: resource:// urls don't load onto iframe and no CSP error gets shown up. There was recommendation that use data.load("simpleframe.html") and then set location of iframe with schema data: but there are pages with CSP to block that. Is the only way is to go back to XUL ?

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox `data:`, `blob:` and `filesystem:` are subject to CSP. Use `chrome:` or `resource:` instead.

update:

Apparently this approach will not work with the Add-on SDK, probably due to sandbox restrictions.

Comment: If we give resource://<extension_id>/<somepath>/data/frame.html it does not load inside the iframe. This path loads on a tab independently. And when it does not load it does not even throw CSP error.

Comment: I am using addon sdk not xul to package the extension

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082162/firefox-addon-sdk-loading-addon-file-into-iframe?rq=1 which says there is an issue with resource but my target webpage has CSP enabled which blocks data:// so I am stuck.