# How to add Content Security Policy to firefox extension when using addon sdk?

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I am using firefox add-on sdk to convert my chrome extension to a firefox addon. But I am getting `Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at data:text/html;charset=utf-8` error. I am injecting a local html in an iframe following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706900/loading-a-local-html-file-in-an-injected-iframe-within-a-firefox-extension). Any idea how to achieve this? For chrome extension I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641592/injecting-iframe-into-page-with-restrictive-content-security-policy).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me.

I add to my package.json the following line:

```
"permissions": {
    "cross-domain-content": ["https://www.foo.com/"]
},
```

Where https://www.foo.com you can add the domain or the list of domains that you are accessing.

For more info go to the [Cross Domain Content Scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts)